# I want to keep a "SQLite" database in my "assets" folder but every time i try to build my project i get a "fatal error"

Tags: android, android-studio

[Folder view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGwH9.jpg)

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
D:\AS Projects\New folder\FirstCompeteProject\app\src\main\res\assets\weight:1:1: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
Error:(1, 1) Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
D:\AS Projects\New folder\FirstCompeteProject\app\src\main\res\assets\weight
```

Comment: Fetal error? Someone is giving birth.

Comment: typo, thanks

my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you are putting in `src/main/res` folder.
You should create the `assets` folder directly under `src/main` directory.